# Connect EC2 instance to Target Group using Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have been working for a while registering **EC2 instances** to **ELB's** using **Ansible**. But now I'm starting to use **ALB's** and I need to connect my instances to **Target Groups** which in turn are connected to the **ALB**. Is there an **Ansible** plugin that allows me to register an instance to a **AWS Target Group**?

Comment: After Googling around I found this Issue opened: https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/issues/4857 I hope that this functionality will be released soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Ansible does not support registration of instances to target groups I had to use the AWS-CLI tool. With the following command you can register an instance to a target group:

```
aws elbv2 register-targets --target-group-arn arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:your-target-group --targets Id=i-your-instance
```

So I just call this command from Ansible and it's done.

Answer (score 0):

Use elb_target:

- name: Gather facts for all new proxy instances
  ec2_instance_facts:
  filters:
    "tag:Name": "{{ ec2_tag_proxy }}"
  register: ec2_proxy
- elb_target_group:
  name: uat-target-proxy
  protocol: http
  port: 80
  vpc_id: vpc-4e6e8112
  deregistration_delay_timeout: 60
  stickiness_enabled: True
  stickiness_lb_cookie_duration: 86400
  health_check_path: /
  successful_response_codes: "200"
  health_check_interval: "20"
  state: present
- elb_target:
  target_group_name: uat-target-proxy
  target_id: "{{ item.instance_id }}"
  target_port: 80
  state: present
  with_items: "{{ ec2_proxy.instances }}"
  when: ec2_proxy.instances|length > 0

Answer (score -1):

Try the following configurations:

```
- name: creating target group
      local_action:
        module: elb_target_group
        region: us-east-2
        vpc_id: yourvpcid
        name: create-targetgrp-delete
        protocol: https
        port: 443
        health_check_path: /
        successful_response_codes: "200,250-260"
        state: present
        targets:
          - Id: ec2isntanceid
            Port: 443
        wait_timeout: 200
      register: tgp
```